# Curious name confusion

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clr

I have the following code of a mini-game(written in CLR, not worthy of a complete reading):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
char map[15][15+1]={
    "###############",
    "#.............#",
    "#.............#",
    "#....#####....#",
    "#.............#",
    "#.............#",
    "#.............#",
    "######...######",
    "#.............#",
    "#.............#",
    "#.............#",
    "#....#####....#",
    "#.............#",
    "#.............#",
    "###############"};
int x1,y1,x2,y2;
int val(int x, int y){
    if(map[y][x]=='#') return 0;
    if(x==x1 && y==y1) return 0;
    if(x==x2 && y==y2) return 0;
    return 1;
}
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int x, y;
    while(1){
        cin>>x>>y;
        if(x<0 || x>=15 || y<0 || y>=15 || map[y][x]=='#')
            continue;
        break;
    }
    while(1){
        cin>>x1>>y1;
        if(x1<0 || x1>=15 || y1<0 || y1>=15 || map[y1][x1]=='#')
            continue;
        break;
    }
    while(1){
        cin>>x2>>y2;
        if(x2<0 || x2>=15 || y2<0 || y2>=15 || map[y2][x2]=='#')
            continue;
        break;
    }
    system("cls");
    for(int i=0;i<15;++i) cout<<map[i]<<endl;
    int d1=1,d2=1,choq=0;
    while(1){
        Sleep(100);
        Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y);
        cout<<".";
        if(_kbhit()){
            int dir=_getch();
            if(dir==72){//ar
                if(val(x,y-1)) y-=1;
                else ++choq;
            }
            if(dir==75){//izq
                if(val(x-1,y)) x-=1;
                else ++choq;
            }
            if(dir==77){//der
                if(val(x+1,y)) x+=1;
                else ++choq;
            }
            if(dir==80){//ab
                if(val(x,y+1)) y+=1;
                else ++choq;
            }
            if(dir=='s' || dir=='S')
                break;
        }
        Console::SetCursorPosition(x1,y1);
        cout<<".";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(x2,y2);
        cout<<".";
        if(map[y1+d1][x1]=='#' || (y1+d1==y && x1==x)){
            if(y1+d1==y && x1==x)++choq;
            d1=-d1;
        }
        if(map[y2+d2][x2]=='#' || (y2+d2==y && x2==x)){
            if(y2+d2==y && x2==x)++choq;
            d2=-d2;
        }
        y1+=d1;
        y2+=d2;
        Console::SetCursorPosition(x1,y1);
        cout<<"#";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(x2,y2);
        cout<<"#";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(x,y);
        cout<<"#";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(0,16);
        cout<<choq <<" choques.";
    }
    Console::SetCursorPosition(0,17);
    cout<<"Simulacion terminada.";
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile, I get errors saying that `x1, y1` are of type `double (_cdecl*)(double)`. If I replace their names by `x_1, y_1` the problem is solved. But, why does this happens? I can't find that definition anywhere in the included headers, and intelliSense doesn't hint me about the parameters or type when I write `x1(` .Moreover, Visual Studio 2012 doesn't complain about the line

```
int x1,y1,x2,y2;
```

being a redefinition.

May you help me to understand this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

They are deprecated [Posix functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/y0.html).  You got them from `<math.h>`, pulled in by `<iostream>`.

The workaround you found is okayish.  These name choices came from an era where programmers had to operate the shift key with their left foot, computers were still competing with desktop calculators and dumping short identifier names in the global namespace was not nearly as much of problem as it is today.  An identifier name like "y1" is fine for an argument or local variable name.

Not so fine for global variables.  Use descriptive names for globals, you still only have to press but a few keys.  The editor's auto-completion feature is your friend.  The reader of your code will thank you, as does the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I know that the structure of my code is not the best, I don't intend it to ever have 100+ lines :) This is indeed an strange error, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I used to get an error like that frequently in Microsoft Developer Studio 6; it stopped happening when I upgraded to Visual Studio 2010. I don't know about the 2012 version.

There had been a definition for y1 (but not x1) hidden deeply within the headers. Try right-clicking on "y1" and selecting "Show definition" from the popup.